# Is there a connection between the Sephirot and Tales of the Abyss?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

While I was playing *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 3*, I was doing an extra lesson on the tarot and Mr Edogawa started talking about the [Sephirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephirot). He then went and mentioned one of its branches and I recognized three from *Tales of the Abyss*:

- Malkuth => the Malkuth Empire which opposes the Kindom of Kimlasca
- Hod => the country that Guy and Mary came from that was destroyed in the previous war
- Chokhmah => as in Grand Chokhmah being the capital of the Malkuth Empire

There was also the fact that Sephirot can be transliterated to English as Sephiroth, which is the name of the tree that keeps the world up and out of the Qliphoth.

This got me wondering: is there a connection between the Sephirot and *Tales of the Abyss*? Or are all of these just coincidences?

Comment: I believe, there is no real connection at all. Simply usage of some known names, which happens always and everywhere. So, connection between Sephirot and Tales of the Abyss is very same to connection between Final Fantasy VII and Norse mythology because of name of town Nibelheim.

Answer (score 1):

Sephiroth in Tales of the Abyss.(TotA) is the name of the stream of energy that supports the upper world. In TotA, the lower world was filled with Miasma so they build a world above it and migrated there. Sephiroth is the collective name of the pillars that branches out to support the above land.

You can read more about Tales of the Abyss' Sephiroth [here](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Sephiroth_Trees).